# Add icon hyperlinks to grouped SP2013 list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, javascript

In SharePoint 2013, I want to take the grouped view of a list and add 3 buttons to the left of each item. In previous versions of SharePoint, I would have duplicated the list view using a DVWP but 2013 has left DVWPs for CSR... and I have no idea how to do this using CSR.

Essentially, all I want to do is tack on 3 icons to the left of each item in the view. Two of the icons are hyperlinks and the third passes the item ID to a workflow via JQuery. Can this be done via a simple JSLink, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs to do this, here is the script I used. It's based on a couple of examples I found through googling, and I've added to it by finding the current item's ID and passing it to the URLs I'm generating. On my list, I created a single line of text column called "Actions" and then placed it in the view where I wanted my buttons to appear. This blank field is simply a placeholder for the icons. The links behind the icons take the user to the initiation form for each workflow (in a modal popup), but you could potentially call a JQuery function that would trigger the workflow directly and skip the Start/Cancel screen altogether.

Obviously, replace the ListID with your source list GUID & the TemplateID with your workflow GUID. An easy way to get this is to go into the workflows screen for one of your items, right-click on the workflow you want to trigger, and copy that shortcut. You can then paste that into Notepad or something and strip off the ItemGUID and source parameters from the URL.

```
//Overrides the value of the Actions field
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Actions': { 'View': renderActionIcons }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}) ();


//Defines the actual override value and generates the icon code
function renderActionIcons(ctx) {
    var itemid = ctx.CurrentItem["ID"];
    var html = "";
    html += "<div style='width:100%;height:20px;position:relative;'>";
    html += "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(&quot;/highrise-sc1/Lists/Virginia%20Projects/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + itemid + "&quot;, RefreshPage);' title='Edit Project'>";
    html += "<img style='margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' src='/style library/images/icons/details.png' border='0' alt='Edit Project'></a>";
    html += "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(&quot;/highrise-sc1/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={1fb3c6e6-8dde-4563-8a6a-1c820042a40f}&ID=" + itemid + "&TemplateID={cf727a1e-363e-4961-bcce-ffa384fe86d4}&quot;, RefreshPage);' title='Copy Project'>";
    html += "<img style='margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' src='/style library/images/icons/copy.png' border='0' alt='Copy Project'></a>";
    html += "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(&quot;/highrise-sc1/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={1fb3c6e6-8dde-4563-8a6a-1c820042a40f}&ID=" + itemid + "&TemplateID={638b64ca-b123-49ee-9533-6343e32c6ca5}&quot;, RefreshPage);' title='Delete Project'>";
    html += "<img style='margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' src='/style library/images/icons/delete.png' border='0' alt='Delete Project'></a>";
    html += "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(&quot;/highrise-sc1/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={1fb3c6e6-8dde-4563-8a6a-1c820042a40f}&ID=" + itemid + "&TemplateID={f7da5ff8-c472-4137-9d24-a91c90a5a912}&quot;, RefreshPage);' title='Promote to Job'>";
    html += "<img style='margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' src='/style library/images/icons/promote.png' border='0' alt='Promote to Job'></a>";
    html += "</div>";
    return html;
}
```

Thanks to the following article for the base script & idea:
[JS Link for SharePoint 2013 Web Parts – A Quick Functional Primer](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/)